# Start with $1 and toss a coin. If it comes up heads your winnings double, if tails you lose all your winnings. What are the expected winnings?

Tags: probability, expected-value, gambling

*You start with 1 dollar and toss a coin. If it comes up heads your winnings double, if it comes up tails you lose all your winnings. What are the expected winnings?*

This seems a variation of St. Petersburg's Paradox to me. Intuitively you are bound to lose everything and therefore end up with 1 dollar less than you started.

Mathematically, I thought about it in two different ways:

1. Let X be the accumulated winnings, then on the next toss you stand to have a net gain of X with probability 1/2 or a net loss of -X with 1/2 i.e 1/2(x)-1/2(x)=0. Therefore your expected gains are zero, you are indifferent and would play the game
2. Let X be the accumulated winnings, then on the next toss you stand to increase your winnings to $2\times$ with probability 1/2, or lose everything (-X) with probability 1/2 i.e $1/2(2x)-1/2(x)=1/2X$. Hence the expected value of the game tends to infinity and you would play the game

I am not confident with any of the above. Any hints or comments would be helpful.

Comment: $E(X) = \frac{1}{2}(0)+\frac{1}{2}(1+E(X))$

Comment: The question is unclear because 'winnings' is not defined

Comment: @Snoop the meaning of winnings seems fairly clear, the number of dollars you get.

Comment: @SuzuHirose what is clear to me is that the answer is different if we ask for expected winnings for finite duration or in the limit

Comment: Based on the simple statement in the first paragraph, I would interpret the problem as flipping a coin exactly once, after which you either have two dollars or nothing. There is no mention of more than one coin flip. But based on your second paragraph you seem to think we keep flipping the coin as long as it comes up heads. Is this problem your own idea (in which case you can make that assumption but should be more explicit about it) or did you get the problem from somewhere else (in which case you might want to check what their assumptions actually are)?

Answer (score 1):

The expected winnings after $n$ turns of the game are
$$\sum x p(x)$$
where $p(x)$ is the probability of winning $x$ dollars. In this case you have $\frac12^n$ chance of winning $2^n$ dollars, and $(1-\frac12^n)$ chance of losing everything, so the expected amount you win is:
$$
\frac12^n \times $2^n + (1-\frac12^n)\times $0 = $1
$$
This result is counterintuitive, since you cannot ever win exactly one dollar playing this game.

Comment: You assume he stops after $n$ turns, for some $n$.  The OP did not say that.

Comment: @GEdgar - the question as I understand it asks what the expected winnings are, and the answer to this rather well-known problem is that the value of the expectation is \$1 for any number of tries. I don't think it matters whether he used the letter $n$ in his question.

Comment: There's no paradox when the expected value of a game is different from every possible outcome of the game. It's just the way the technical term "expected value" is defined.

Comment: @DavidK perhaps "paradox" is the wrong word here.

Answer (score 0):

Suzu's answer shows that if you agree to stop after $n$ turns (where $n$ is determined in advance), then your expected final fortune is $1$.

Second version.  I will never stop.  Then (according to the Borel-Cantelli lemma) I eventually get tails, and so I eventually lose everything.

Comment: *almost surely* eventually get tails, i.e. with probability $1$, but not *surely*

Comment: Correct, almost surely.  So the expectation is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The sample space for this situation is $\Omega=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb N}$, (0 for loosing, 1 for winning) with Bernoulli's measure $P$, while the random variable $X$ is the constant function zero, except that
$$
X(1,1,1,\ldots)=\infty.
$$
Therefore
$$
E(X)=\int_\Omega X(\omega)\,dP(\omega)=0.
$$

In case you decide to stop after $n$ turns, then the relevant random variable is
$$
X_n = 2^n 1_{C_n},
$$
where $1_{C_n}$ is the characteristic function of the cylinder
$$C^n=\{1\}\times\{1\}\times\cdots\times\{1\}\times\{0,1\}^\infty.
$$
Even though $X_n\to X$ almost everywhere, the integrals do not converge, that is,
$$
\lim_n\int_\Omega X_n(\omega)\,dP(\omega)
\neq\int_\Omega X(\omega)\,dP(\omega),
$$
mainly because Lebesgue's dominated convergence Theorem doesn't apply.